# Move users and program files to another PC

Tags: windows-10, migration

I have a clean install of Win10, and I have a working install of Win10 on another PC. I want to move now all my setup to the new install of Win10.

Basically I have Users, Program Files (both of them), ProgramData top level folders and I want to move them to the new PC to avoid reinstalling and re-configuring stuff. I know how to copy these properly to preserve all the attributes and folder junkctions/links (I use awesome [strarc](http://www.ltr-data.se/files/strarc.txt) for that). The question is: what else needs to be done to migrate my PC configurations/setup to another machine, as simply moving these folders isn't enough.

I'm sure I also need to copy/move `Windows\System32\config`, but is there anything else?

Comment: What you're proposing doing is not possible. If that's what you want, even going so far as to try to overwrite the registry, you might as well just keep the old hard drive, or clone it to the new computer along with all the junk.

Comment: That's essentially what I'm trying to do. Windows folder on old HD got messed up and I want to restore all other stuff except the WIndows folder. The reason it happened: after update my pc wouldn't boot. When I was trying to fix it, I noticed that I had Windows.old and deleted it all (thinking it was from some time ago). Only later I figured our that PC stopped working because of failed updated and Windows.old was the version that worked and I deleted it.

Comment: I would consider cloning old machine with clonezilla or similar and restoring the clone to new machine